# How can I use LuaLaTeX for `europasscv`?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia

I want to write a `europasscv` in the same format as my other material for application etc., for which I use `LuaLaTeX`. The problem up to now is that I can't even make use of `TeX Gyre Heros` as sansfont, which is the mainfont in `europassv`. `euopasscv` doesn't seem to accept neither `LuaLaTex` nor `fontspec`.

```
% -- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; --
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\documentclass[german,a4paper,heros]{europasscv} %I've defined europasscv_de.def and (inside europasscv.cls) \DeclareOption{heros}{\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qhv}\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv}} AFTER it failed the first times
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}% [ItalicFont=TeXGyreHeros-Italic,
%              BoldFont=TeXGyreHeros-Bold,
%              BoldItalicFont=TeXGyreHeros-BoldItalic]
\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}% [ItalicFont=TeXGyreHeros-Italic,
%              BoldFont=TeXGyreHeros-Bold,
%              BoldItalicFont=TeXGyreHeros-BoldItalic]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[latesthyphen=true,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\ecvname{My Self}
\ecvaddress{Townstreet, D-12345 Town}
\ecvtelephone[(+49) 1234 5689]{(+49) 1234 56789}
\ecvemail{My.Self@me.me}
\ecvnationality{deutsch}
\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}
  \ecvpersonalinfo
  \ecvbigitem{Angestrebter Beruf}{Bla}
  \ecvsection{Berufserfahrung}
  \ecvtitle{Oktober 2003 -- Juli 2004}{\emph{teaching fellow}}
  \ecvitem{}{Council\newline 123, Sample Kay, 75023 Smurftown}
  \ecvitem{}{Evaluation of Smurfs}
\end{europasscv}
\end{document}
```

I tried a lot: `\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{qhv}
\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{qhv}
\renecommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}, texgyreheros-regular.otf` instead of `TeX Gyre Heros` ... Nothings works. `.log`ix complains

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape EU2/qhv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              usingEU2/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 20.
[...]
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
* you should not be loading the inputenc package
* XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding %<--I'm not using XeTeX!
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape EU2/phv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              usingEU2/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 40.
```

As a result I neither get `Heros` as sansfont nor does it use any other sansfont. Instead it uses only `LMRoman`. Without `fontspec` and `polyglossia` it works with `LuaLaTeX`, but then I can't use neither the fonts I'd like to nor specials of the german language.

Comment: If you wan't to prevent the loading of packages you can use `\RequirePackage{scrlfile}\PreventPackageFromLoading{inputenc}`.

Comment: In my TeXlive installation I don't have a `europasscv.cls` file, but only a `europecv.cls` file. Is it a custom class?

Comment: Useful -- but it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Astrinus: It's there in TeXLive 2014, quite new

Comment: It is a f[ra]cking new class: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux), and `kpsewhich` doesn't find neither `europasscv` nor `europasscv.cls`.

Comment: @Astrinus: Daily update?

Comment: With the suggested `scrlfile` etc., `.log`ix says `Package scrlfile Warning: package 'inputenc' already loaded.
(scrlfile)                Cannot prevent it from beeing loaded on input line 6.` and `*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.` So, the problem is `inputenc` and `XeTeX` instead of `LuaTeX`.

Comment: In `europasscv` environment, there is an explicit font change to `phv`, so this will probably fail unless patched

Comment: hm, that's why I wrote `\DeclareOption{heros}{%
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qhv}
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv}
}` in the class-file and used `heros` as option for `documentclass`. Tomorrow I'll try to rewrite the class.

Comment: Is `qhv` the family name?

Comment: `qhv` is one of them -- none of the possible ones (`texgyreheros`, `gyreheros`, `heros` ...) worked.

Answer (score 5):

The `europasscv` is **not** really designed for usage with some other font and with `xelatex/lualatex` compilation.

One way is to use the brute force and explicitly add `\sffamily` to the various `\ecv...` commands and finally, within the `europasscv` environment.

```
%\RequirePackage{xparse}
\documentclass[german,a4paper]{europasscv} %I've defined europasscv_de.def and (inside europasscv.cls) \DeclareOption{heros}{\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qhv}\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv}} AFTER it failed the first times
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[
        Extension=.otf,
        UprightFont= *-regular,
        BoldFont=*-bold,
        ItalicFont=*-italic,
        BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]{texgyreheros}

    \setromanfont{texgyreheros}
    \setsansfont[Extension=.otf,
        UprightFont= *-regular,
        BoldFont=*-bold,
        ItalicFont=*-italic,
        BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic]
    {texgyreheros}% 

    \usepackage{polyglossia}

    \usepackage{xpatch}



    \makeatletter
    \ecvfootnote{\protect\sffamily\textcopyright~\ecv@europeanunionkey, 2002-2014 | http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu }
    \makeatother


    \renewcommand{\ecvcoloredtitle}{\sffamily\textcolor{ecvhighlightcolor}{\ecvcurrvitae}}
    \renewcommand{\ecvsectionstyle}[1]{\textcolor{ecvsectioncolor}{\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\expandafter{#1}}}}
    \renewcommand{\ecvbluenormalstyle}[1]{\sffamily\textcolor{ecvsectioncolor}{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\ecvtitlestyle}[1]{\large{\ecvbluenormalstyle{#1}}}
    \renewcommand{\ecvlargenormalstyle}[1]{\large \sffamily #1}
    \renewcommand{\ecvLargenormalstyle}[1]{\Large \sffamily #1}


    \setmainlanguage[latesthyphen=true,babelshorthands=true]{german}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

    \ecvname{My Self}
    \ecvaddress{Townstreet, D-12345 Town}
    \ecvtelephone[(+49) 1234 5689]{(+49) 1234 56789}
    \ecvemail{My.Self@me.me}
    \ecvnationality{deutsch}

    \begin{document}
      \begin{europasscv}
        \sffamily % Explicitly switch to sans serif
        \ecvpersonalinfo
        \ecvbigitem{Angestrebter Beruf}{Bla}
        \ecvsection{Berufserfahrung}
        \ecvtitle{Oktober 2003 -- Juli 2004}{\emph{teaching fellow}}
        \ecvitem{}{Council\newline 123, Sample Kay, 75023 Smurftown}
        \ecvitem{}{Evaluation of Smurfs}
    \end{europasscv}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the current `fontspec` manual, `\setromanfont` is the old form of `\setmainfont` and is retained only for backward compatibility. Since the example code features a `\setmainfont` instruction, the `\setromanfont` is redundant. Separately, the options passed to the `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` instructions are all the default ones for an otf font, and those options may thus be omitted as well. A final, truly minor, quibble: In the argument of `\ecvfootnote`, I'd write `2002--2014` rather than `2002-2014` in order to get an en-dash...

Comment: <quote>The europasscv is not really designed for usage with some other font</quote> I'd agree if and only if there weren't options defined in the `.cls`file: `% Set font
\DeclareOption{helvetica}{%                       
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
}` (the other option is `arial`, so I added `heros` as a third one, expecting that if `arial` worked, `heros` would do the same).

Comment: @Mico: I am not very into xelatex so far, you I appreciate your comments of course. The `--` stuff I just copied from the class ... blame the maintainer ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann: There is a new version of `europasscv` on TeXLive (I don't check so far), perhaps it's improved

Comment: It has not. I can use LuaLaTeX for almost all of my documents, but here it fails -- with your modifications above and some by me, it works for the most part in the main text, but not in the footer (why the f[ra]ck is `\ecvpage` defined inside `\DeclareOption{hungarian}{`?).